# Which is the fastest way to fill an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function which will be called many times throughout my code. This function updates 2 values(passed as argument) in an array. Since it is called too many times, I want this function optimized.

Yes I do have a simplest code to do that,

```
int global_array[MAX];
int * ptr_to_my_global_array = &global_array[0];

main()
{
  int a=0,b=0;

  my_func(a,b);
  a++;b++;
  my_func(a,b);
  a++;b++;
  my_func(a,b);
  a++;b++;
  my_func(a,b);
  a++;b++;
  my_func(a,b);
  a++;b++;
  //and so on
}

void my_func(int c,int d)
{

   *ptr_to_my_global_array = c;
   ptr_to_my_global_array++;
   *ptr_to_my_global_array = d;
   ptr_to_my_global_array++;

}
```

Please do not suggest any mem_copy,mem_set solutions. There may be no other solution, but was just curious if I could make this faster.

Comment: Its extremely doubtful in my experience that you can outdo memset or memcpy. This comes from years of experience of replacing various naive memory setting/copying with memset and memcpy

Comment: @DougT. You are absolutely right. If i could id +10 the comment and IMHO you should make it an answer.

Comment: @DougT :My problem is, if I use mem_copy/set, it will add to the throughput of the code as it is a function call(assuming its a call made inside my_func). So this is not recommended. If you feel that would be faster, you may suggest me.

Comment: @kartik memxxx calls are often inlined by state of the art compilers. That's why they are so hard to beat.

Comment: BTW I assume that you have actually profiled your code and identified the bottleneck before getting worried about function call overheads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're testing out different things, you could compare it against:

```
inline void my_func(int c,int d)
{
ptr_to_my_global_array[0] = c;
ptr_to_my_global_array[1] = d;
ptr_to_my_global_array += 2;
}
```

Probably the optimizer will sort things out so that there's no difference between the two, but you might as well see what difference (if any) it makes to the emitted code.

Basically, your function is so simple that it's difficult to see how a human could do anything better than the optimizer does. So any real improvement to your program would need to be in `main` rather than in `my_func`.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking something on these lines. I cannot optimize in main function. I was also thinking if there could be any bitwise operators that could do the job faster. I am accepting this as answer, since this was closest. Not sure if something can be better.

Answer (score 2):

Use a macro, instead of function call, which might take away the overhead of calling a function. However you might find that the compiler optimisation does this already.

Benchmark and test :-)